# When redirecting to a route under a container, the child components won't get rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have several session routes like `/login` and `/forgotpassword`. I wrap these routes in the `SessionContainer`. The rest of the routes I wrap in the `MainAppContainer`. My app looks like this:

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <div className="App" >
        <ProgressBar />

        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <div>
            <div id="container">
              <Switch>
                <SessionContainer>
                  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                  <Route exact path="/forgotpassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
                </SessionContainer>

                <MainAppContainer>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                </MainAppContainer>
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
```

In the app container, I check whether the user is there in my redux state and redirect the user to the app if true. In the app container I reidrect to login if the user is not there. Example (My app container):

```
const MainAppContainer = ({ children, user }) => {
  if (user) {
    return (<div>
      <Sidebar />

      <MainContainer>
        <UserMenu />

        <InnerContainer>
          {children}
        </InnerContainer>
      </MainContainer>
    </div>);
  }
  return <Redirect to="/login" />;
};
```

The problem is, if I go to the app without logging in, the redirection happens as intended but, only the session container is loaded. The child components are not getting loaded. Any idea why this is happening?

I also tried redirecting only if the path matches. Still, it won't load the child components. If I go to the page directly it loads everything. But if redirected, the child components won't render:

```
const MainAppContainer = ({ children, user, location }) => {
  if (user) {
    return (<div>
      <Sidebar />

      <MainContainer>
        <UserMenu />

        <InnerContainer>
          {children}
        </InnerContainer>
      </MainContainer>
    </div>);
  }

  if (location.pathname !== '/login') {
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
  }
  return null;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { user } = state.session;

  return {
    user
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(MainAppContainer));
```

I tried to reproduce the issue in sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/github/THPubs/react-router-multiple-containers) but in there sometimes the error comes but sometimes it won't. I added the code here: https://github.com/THPubs/react-router-multiple-containers.

If you can clone it, `yarn install` and `yarn start` then you'll see the issue. Go to `/login`. You should see two titles. Then go to `/`. It will get redirected to `/login` and the title that says login won't be there. When preparing the code I noticed that it happens only when we attach redux!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an endless redirection, based on your code. This line is executed no matter what the path is:

```
  <MainAppContainer>
     <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  </MainAppContainer>
```

Now let's say you go to "/" without logging first. This is what happens:

1. The MainAppContainer is rendered. Since you have not logged in, `<Redirect to="/login" />` is rendered.
2. Back to the main app, the MainAppContainer is rendered again.
3. Since you have not logged in, `<Redirect to="/login" />` is rendered. This is an endless redirection.

Solution:
Check the current pathname before deciding to redirect or not.

```
  if (user) {
    return (<div>
      <Sidebar />

      <MainContainer>
        <UserMenu />

        <InnerContainer>
          {children}
        </InnerContainer>
      </MainContainer>
    </div>);
  }

  else {
    // exclude the next line from being rendered on `/login`
    if (props.location.pathname !== '/login') {
      return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Also, you need to call `withRouter()` with `MainAppContainer` to make this solution works. Since `MainAppContainer` does not have access to `props.location`

Final Solution:
To solve the `forgotpassword` issue, modify the MainAppContainer to:

```
const MainAppContainer = ({ children, user, location }) => {
  console.log(`MainApp : ${location.pathname}`);

  // When the current path is '/login' or '/forgotpassword',
  // do not render anything.
  if ((location.pathname === '/login') || (location.pathname === '/forgotpassword')) {
    return null;
  }
  else {
    if (user) {
      const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children,
        child => React.cloneElement(child, {
          pathname: location.pathname
        })
      );



      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Session container.</h2>

          {childrenWithProps}
        </div>
      );
    }


    return <Redirect push to="/login" />;
  }

};
```

Comment: Thanks I modified the containers like that but still it's not working. When I directly load the page the content is loaded. But if I get to the page because of a redirect, the children won't be loaded.

Comment: Could you please check the content of `location.pathname` using `console.log(location.pathname)` inside the `MainAppContainer`? I doubt you have set the `withRouter` correctly. It should be `export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(MainAppContainer));`.

Comment: Console log gives the pathname but there's a problem. If I visit `/` it prints `/` and re-directs to `/login`. I also have a console log in login. But it won't get called if redirected. If I visit login directly, that console log will be called and I get `/login` as the pathname.

Comment: do you mind to share the complete code via codesandbox or codepen? I would like to check it directly if you don't mind.

Comment: I tried in sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/github/THPubs/react-router-multiple-containers) but in there sometimes the error comes but sometimes it won't. I added the code here: https://github.com/THPubs/react-router-multiple-containers If you can clone it, `yarn install` and `yarn start` then you'll see the issue. Go to `/login`. You should see two titles. Then go to `/`. It will get redirected to `/login` and the title that says login won't be there. When preparing the code I noticed that it happens only when we attach redux!

Comment: Ehm, I see. Please modify these two lines to: `export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(MainAppContainer));` (in the `MainAppContainer`), and `export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(SessionContainer));` (in the `SessionContainer`). I check here, it now works. Please try it and let me know the result. If it really works, I will revise my answer and explain it.

Comment: Now that solves one problem but give rise to another. Now I can't visit any route other than `/` and `/login`. All others redirect to one of them. For example, try to visit `/forgotpassword`. I use an if and prevent the redirect from running but then I have to add all the routes in the app which might get messy.

Comment: I think I solved the problem! First thanks a lot for your help! I took the routes to a different file and now check the user's existence in there and output only the relevant routes. If user, only the app route. If not only the session routes. Then I take the location prop from there and pass to the containers. This works perfectly for now.

Comment: No problem, glad to be able to help. I just revised my code above to provide the solution for `forgotpassword` as well. Regarding the withRouter problem, read the explanation here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter